# Xbox 360 can't connect to internet

Tags: networking, router, xbox360

What happened: we went on holiday for a week, leaving all gadgets at home unplugged from the mains electricity.  When we got back, the Xbox 360 could no longer log on to Xbox Live.  All our other gadgets can connect to the internet as normal using a mix of Ethernet and wireless connections.

The router is a Zyxel VMG1312-B10D.

The Xbox 360 error messages are as follows.

When selecting an account to log on to Xbox Live, the Xbox 360 responds with:

Your console can't connect to Xbox Live.

8015190E

I then tried testing the Xbox live connection using the Xbox 360.

This reports that the Xbox 360 can connect to the home network, but "can't connect to internet".

Suggestion 1 says MTU error and recommends unplugging the router/modem from the power for 5 minutes.  Suggestion 2 says MTU error: visit www.xbox.com/mtu-help for more help.

I tried both suggestions.  www.xbox.com/mtu-help doesn't exist any more.  I found several recommendations on-line that say Xbox Live requires an MTU set between 1364 minimum and 1492 maximum.  I checked my router: it had MTU set to 1458.

I looked for help on-line and followed recommendations to do these things:

1) Turn on Universal PnP - I had already done this when we got the Xbox 360, and UPnP was still turned on when I checked.

Specifically, the router settings for: UPnP and UPnP NAT-T are both enabled.  It says that "UPnP NAT-T only works when NAT is enable" (yes, "enable" not "enabled").

When I look at the UPnP setting on my router, it reports an Xbox at IP address 192.168.1.233 with a connection: external port and internal port 3074, protocol UDP.

2) Try a wired home network connection: I plugged the Xbox 360 into the home Ethernet and told the Xbox 360 to use it.

3) Reset the Xbox 360 network settings using Network settings: Restore To Factory Defaults.

4) Clear the Xbox 360 cache.

5) Set manual firewall rules to open up the ports listed here:

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/networking/network-ports-used-xbox-live

6) Set NAT to do port mapping like this:

```
                            : Start  : End  : Map 
     Description : Protocol : port   : port : port

     Xbox 360        TCP      53       53     53
     Xbox 360        UDP      53       53     53
     Xbox 360        UDP      88       88     88
     Xbox 360        TCP      3074     3074   3074
     Xbox 360        UDP      3074     3074   3074
```

I tried all the above suggestions, and after making the last changes powered off the router/modem and Xbox 360 both.  I left the router/modem for the recommended five minutes, then plugged in and powered up the Xbox 360 again. The Xbox 360 still can't connect to the Internet.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: You should be using this [troubleshooter](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/networking/connection-error-solution) to solve your problem instead of [xbox.com/mtu-help](www.xbox.com/mtu-help)

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. The guide you linked to suggests that when faced with my problem, I should reset the Xbox 360 network settings to factory defaults.  That is one of the steps that I had tried, and it didn't fix the problem.

Also, the troubleshooting guide does not list MTU error as a possible problem when the connection test fails between the Network and Internet stages (which is the problem I've got).  The MS troubleshooter lists MTU error only as a possible failure between "Internet" and "Xbox Live".

Comment: I followed the guide to the point where it suggested setting the DMZ to the Xbox IP.  That didn't help either.  I don't have a separate modem and router so I can't try a direct to modem connection. The final suggestion from MS is that there may be an issue with my modem or ISP: since all our other internet devices work fine, I doubt that is the case.

Comment: Exactly the same story, changed MTU didn't help me :( it for one try said that it could connect to 'Internet' but then bailed on xbox live and after reboot bailed on Internet again.

Answer (score 2):

The following procedure suggested elsewhere solved my problem:

- System settings > storage > hard drive. Press Y and delete the cache.
- System settings > storage
- Enter the following button sequence: X, LB, RB, X, LB, RB, X
- Select the option to roll back all system updates that are installed. The console will restart automatically.
- Disconnect your router and turn off your console for 5 minutes.
- Once your router is back online, go back to your xbox and complete the update.

Comment: I deleted the system store cache, but that didn't seem to help. What did was removing the update by entering that code. Network status is now connected instead of unknown. Thanks!

Comment: Did the same, didn't help :(